# multi execute connection windows display the same session information of one container

Tags: docker, containers

In my CentOS server I use docker created a container,

I opened two sessions connected to the container by command:

```
docker attach container-name
```

[image]

but there is an issue, in each window I execute command the other window is display the same information.
so I cannot control the container when it is installing package.

is it possible to avoid this issue?

Comment: Why not `docker exec` another shell?

Comment: do you mean `docker attach` only get one session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`docker attach`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/) command attaches to the currently running process as defined by `CMD`. You can attach as many times as you want, but they all connect to the same process.

If you want to access the container and have different sessions to it, use:

```
docker exec -it container-name bash
```

Or whatever shell is available. `bash` is common, but you may need to use `sh` or find out what's used, if any is there at all. Some containers are super stripped down.

The `-it` flag enables "interactive" mode, as otherwise it just runs that command and shows you the output.

Comment: What do you mean of "currently running process as defined by `CMD`"?

Comment: Each `Dockerfile` defines a [default process that runs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) when it's started. This is often a server process of some kind, but sometimes `sleep` just to keep it idle and running. Remember, a container with no active process is considered dead and is shut down.